Strange method to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+\frac{x}{3})^{1/x}$, but what's the error?
I am not sure what should I call this type of limit calculation... it's not precise, and the result is also wrong. But I can't explicitly find the error of this.

Problem: Find the error of calculating $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+\frac{x}{3})^{1/x}$ using this method.
Let $x$ be a number that is very close to $0$. Then $\frac{3+x}{e^x}\approx \frac{3}{1}$, $1+\frac{x}{3}\approx e^x$. So $(1+\frac{x}{3})^{1/x}\approx e$. The answer is $e$.

The true value of the limit is $e^{\frac{1}{3}}$. I know there must be an error because through this method there can be infinite answers, when I change $\frac{3+x}{e^x}\approx \frac{3}{1}$ to $\frac{3+x}{e^{nx}}\approx \frac{3}{1}$ where $n$ can be any real number. I also guessed that problem occured while going from $1+\frac{x}{3}\approx e^x$ to $(1+\frac{x}{3})^{\frac{1}{x}}\approx e$. However, I am struggling to explicitly write the error, which the problem requires as an answer. What will be the most convincing answer? Also, what type of limits can be calculated accurately using this method? If you provide some thoughts about it it will be really helpful.

Composition of approximation always goes wrong

As a rule, when you have an indeterminate form, like $0^{\infty}$, you can't take the limit in  stages, as you have done.

It depends on what $\approx$ means.
If $f(x) \approx g(x)$ means $f(x) - g(x) = o(1)$, then yes, we can't go from $f(x) \approx g(x)$ to $f(x)^{\frac{1}{x}} \approx g(x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$.
If $\approx$ is stricter, for example $f(x) \approx g(x)$ means $f(x) - g(x) = o(x)$, then you can go from $f(x) \approx g(x)$ (if $f(x) = 1 + O(x)$) to $f(x)^{\frac{1}{x}} - g(x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = o(1)$, but it's no longer true that $\frac{3 + x}{e^x} \approx \frac{3}{1}$.

Sorry, but I'm not familiar with big O notation. I understood everything else but how do we prove that $f(x)-g(x)=o(x)$, then $f(x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-g(x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=o(x)$?

That was actually my mistake - we can get only $o(1)$ in the right part, not $o(x)$ (and for this we need $f$ to be close enough to $1$). Precisely, if $f(x) = 1 + O(x)$ and $h(x) = o(x)$, then $(f(x) + h(x))^{1/x} = \exp(\ln f(x) / x + \ln(1 + h(x) / f(x)) / x) = (f(x))^{1/x} \cdot \exp(o(1)) = (f(x))^{1/x} + o((f(x))^{1/x})$.

Let us do things right first, then see where we can do them wrong.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\exp \frac x3 &=
1+ \frac x3 +O(x^2)\ ,\\
\frac x3&=\log\exp \frac x3 
= \log\left(1+ \frac x3 +O(x^2)\right)
= \log\left(\ \left(1+ \frac x3\right)\left(1 +O(x^2)\right)\ \right)
\\
&= \log\left(1+ \frac x3\right)+O(x^2)\ ,
\\
\frac 13
&=
 \frac 1x\log\left(1+ \frac x3\right)+O(x)
=
 \log\left(\ \left(1+ \frac x3\right)^{1/x}\ \right)+O(x)\ ,
\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and in the last line we can go to the limit with $x\to 0$, so that
$$
\frac 13
=
\lim_{x\to 0}
 \log\left(\ \left(1+ \frac x3\right)^{1/x}\ \right)\ .
$$
It remains to take $\exp$ in the last relation and switch the order of $\exp$
(a continuous function) with the limit.

Let us do now things "wrong". We use $\exp x$ instead of $\exp\frac x3$. Then this "approximation" is less precise, and we must give up $O(x^2)$ in the first line above, use only $O(x)$. All other $O$-ideals go down in precision, and finally, instead of $O(x)$ we have only $O(1)$, and cannot do better. But there is in general no limit with $x\to 0$ for a function in $O(1)$. (When $O(x)$ is involved instead, we have the limit because of a "sandwich criterion" that can be applied.)
